# range of substring in a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an array containing object let say { my saxophone, take, everywhere}. Secondly i have a `NSString`: 'take my saxophone everywhere' then how can I able to match object of array with string and get index from `NSString`. I need index of substring from `NSString` by comparing with objects of array. So that i can sort the array correctly. So far I have done

```
NSRange range = [feedBackAnswer rangeOfString:@"everywhere"];
        if ( range.length > 0 ) 
        {
            NSLog(@"range.location..%d",range.location);
        } 
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"...%d",-1);
        }
```

But I could not find the index of substring.

Comment: I just want to clarify if `everwhere` a typo or not?

Comment: "Typo" means you misspelled the word in transcribing it to this post, vs misspelling "everywhere" everywhere (or, worse, only some places).

Comment: you have to code the finding an `NSString` content in an `NSArray` of `NSString` objects for yourself, there is no special method for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    NSMutableArray * data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"my saxophone",@"take",@"everwhere", nil];
        NSString * mat=@"take my saxophone everywhere";
        for (int i=0; i<[data count]; i++) {
            NSRange range = [mat rangeOfString:[data objectAtIndex:i]];
            if (range.length > 0)
                NSLog(@"Range is: %@", NSStringFromRange(range));
            else
                NSLog(@"Failed"); 
        }

[data release];
```

& check the spelling in array (**everwhere**)

Answer (score 0):

Range of sub string in a string is ...

```
   0: U

   1: n

   2: i

   3: v

   4: e

   5: r

   6: s

   7: i

   8: t

   9: y
```

Comment: i need index of substring like 'take' or 'everywhere' in string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"my",@"saxophone",@"take",@"everywhere", nil];

NSString *str1 = @"take my saxophone everywhere";

NSArray *array = [str1 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@" objects : %@",array);

for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<[array count]; j++) {
    if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[array1 objectAtIndex:j]]) {
        NSLog(@"String :%@ no : %d ",[array objectAtIndex:i],j);
        }
    }
}
```